# Recieve url params with @api_view FBV

Tags: django-rest-framework

Is it possible to pass parameters from URL to a view function decorated with @api_view or I need to use APIView class instead?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes it's possible. What you've to do is access the [**`request.query_params`**](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/requests/#query_params) as below,

```
@api_view()
def sample_view(request, kw, *args,**kwargs):
    url_params = request.query_params
    # ypur code
```